# Tkinter Pandas Python App - Not Getting Value and Performing Calculation

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm fairly new to Python/Pandas/Tkinter and I'm attempting to build a tkinter application that can receive numerical inputs and then perform a WAC (weighted average coupon rate) calculation based on the given input.

[image]

I bring in a dataset via pandas dataframe with three columns - Original Amount, Loan Rate and Special Project Code. I then create a new column, Rate Weight, that is the product of the Original Amount and Loan Rate columns.

The purpose of the app is to receive input from a user for a certain code value that changes the row values in the Loan Rate column based on what interest rate input they give, then a new WAC calculation is performed and shown. So far I only have one input box for one code, code 3231 (not shown above in the sample image).

When I run the app and input a numerical value in the box and click 'Calculate WAC' it returns the   normal WAC value of the dataset, but not a WAC value performed with the new interest rate for code 3231. It seems to me I'm not capturing the value for the rate and properly and replacing the old with the new.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
root.title("Financing Grid") 
root.geometry("600x600")


global df

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\mhorv656\\Documents\\Financing Grid v4.xlsx", "Data",
    engine = 'openpyxl', usecols = ['ORIG_AMT', 'LOAN_RATE', 'SPECIAL_PROJ_CD'])

df['ORIG_AMT'] = df['ORIG_AMT'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df["Rate_WT"] = df["ORIG_AMT"] * df["LOAN_RATE"]
df['SPECIAL_PROJ_CD'] = df['SPECIAL_PROJ_CD'].fillna(0).astype(int)


# Codes 
def c3231_code():
    c3231_frame.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)

    # Creating Input Box
    global c3231_input
    #c3231_input = IntVar()
    c3231_input = Entry(c3231_frame)
    c3231_input.pack(pady = 5)

    # Creating Answer Button
    c3231_button = Button(c3231_frame, text = "Calculate WAC", command = c3231_wac)
    c3231_button.pack(pady = 5)

    # Creating Correct or Incorrect Message
    global c3231_label
    c3231_label = Label(c3231_frame, text = "Enter Rate Above")
    c3231_label.pack(pady = 5)


def c3231_wac():
    df.loc[df['SPECIAL_PROJ_CD'] == '3231', 'LOAN_RATE'] = int(c3231_input.get())
    
    WAC = df["Rate_WT"].sum() / df["ORIG_AMT"].sum()
    WAC_label = Label(c3231_frame, text = WAC)
    WAC_label.pack(pady = 5)

    # Clearing the answer box
    c3231_input.delete(0, 'end')



# Creating a Hide Frame Function
def hide_menu_frames():
    # Destroying the children widgets in each frame
    for widget in c3231_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


    # Hiding all frames
    c3231_frame_frame.pack_forget()

    start_frame.pack_forget()

# Creating Frames
c3231_frame = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 400)
start_frame = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 400)

# Creating Start Screen 
def home():
    start_frame.pack(fill = "both", expand = 1)
    start_label = Label(start_frame, text = "Performing WAC Calculation", font = ("Helvetica", 18)).pack(pady = 40) 

# Creating buttons to codes
c3231_button = Button(start_frame, text = "Enter Rate for 3231", command = c3231_code).pack(pady = 5)

# Defining a Main Menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = my_menu)

# Creating Menu Items
app_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "Finance Grid", menu = app_menu)
app_menu.add_separator()
app_menu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = root.quit)


# Showing the Start Screen
home()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In the c3231_wac() function you are comparing an int value with the string `'SPECIAL_PROJ_CD'] == '3231'`, change: 3231.
2. After the replacement, you must recalculate the value of the "Rate_WT" column and only then calculate the WAC.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I appreciate your response!